# IDE with better Maven support than Eclipse with m2e?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

We are using maven for manage multi-module projects and Eclipse with m2e for development.

Unfortunately Eclipse by itself does not understand the way Maven works, and even if m2e does a lot of work to make the "a parent pom with modules" Maven way look like the "several logically independent projects" Eclipse way it breaks when I e.g. add a new module to the parent pom.  If Maven was a first class citizen I would expect Eclipse to pick up the new module immediately as a new Maven project.

Is there another IDE which has better Maven support, or should I instead lobby the m2e folks?

Comment: Some years later I've worked quite a bit with IntelliJ and it has much better Maven support than Eclipse.  The m2e folks are very talented but it is very clear that they have not been able to change the core functionality of Eclipse to get a better experience.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't work alot with it, but for my knowledge, Netbeans IDE seems to have a quite good maven integration.

Just give it a try on a short example project!

Comment: Yes the Maven integration is rock solid; the IDE works cleaner than eclipse. IntelliJ IDEA, if using Java EE, would mean buying licenses, but offers much intelligence, and is definitely faster than eclipse on opening hundreds of projects (Maven projects tend to be smaller). I would pick NetBeans first though.

Comment: @JoopEggen - its perfectly possible to work on a large j2ee project using intellij idea (using maven to build it). the commercial edition does provide higher level support in terms of inspections, highlighting and auto-completion, but you dont _have_ to buy a license.

Comment: @radai: misunderstood - I meant indeed, that IntelliJ can start with hundred of projects in a sec, whereas eclipse takes very long. The commercial edition is better than both eclipse and NetBeans on the points you mention. Working with the community edition on j2ee however is then quite painful in contrast. Only therefore NetBeans.

Comment: in netbeans and intJ i don't see anything even near to eclipse m2e's quality, the dependency hierarchy  tab the best thing in maven. simply because maven tree doesn't do filtering

Answer (score 0):

1st of all lobbying the m2e folks is always good - better support for maven is always a good thing.

having said that i work on a ~200-modules maven project using [intellij idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). its maven support (which is available in their community edition) is simply great - you dont even need the maven idea plugin to create your project, you just import your pom directly.

it will also correctly handle changes you make to your pom - just add a new  to a parent pom and idea will actually offer to create the corresponding directory and child pom for you. and after that it will add the new child module to the project. it also supports "conditional" child modules - modules defined under various profiles. when you enable/disable maven profiles (maven panel, right side of the IDE) it will correctly add/remove child modules to/from the idea project.

not that for larger projects you would want to turn this auto-import off and manually re-import your project (idea will prompt you, or worst-case there's a button for it on the maven panel) as automatically reimporting very large projects will be noticable.

idea will correctly map multi-module tree-like projects into idea multi-module project and will automatically pick up on your libraries, dependencies, maven profiles, etc. its also very easy to execute maven operations directly from it (maven panel on the right side of the IDE).

it doesnt pick on some of our more complicated build steps (we have some utility bound to he lifecycle that generates some of our source code using the maven exec plugin and if you just do a project-->build all from intellij its not picked up for example) but those things arent common. also, you can get around this by executing maven directly from the IDE instead of trying to build from the IDE.

not perfect, but the best i've seen.

Comment: +1 for IntelliJ and Maven. It is superior to any other IDE I've ever used. BTW could you try to start your sentences with capital letters? It makes it much easier to read.