# does maven supports any IDE except from eclipse?

Tags: maven, jcreator

I'm using JCreator instead of Eclipse in creating programs, I just to ask if maven supports different IDE's except from eclipse?

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IDE with better Maven support than Eclipse with m2e?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188038/ide-with-better-maven-support-than-eclipse-with-m2e)

Answer (score 1):

JCreator doesn't have any built in support for Maven, so if you want to use Maven with it, you'll have to do it from the command line.

As for other IDE's, both IntelliJ and Netbeans have support for Maven.